# RegEx: Capture action params

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a [regex](http://regex101.com/r/nK9zO1/1) to capture the params of an URL REST action. I wrote the following:

```
(?:\/folder)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+
```

It works great for `/folder/one/two/three`, and I get *one*, *two* and *three* as result. If I try just `/folder/` or `/folder` I get *folder* as result, but I don't want to capture it. I'm expecting an empty result.

How can I negate this whole word, in this case?

Comment: what would you like to see for `/somethingelse/one/two/three` and for `/folderandmore/one/two/three`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to use PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
(?:^(?:\/folder\/?)|^.*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/13)

Comment: Almost there, we have the matches, now I need the found words. PHP `preg_match_all()` will return them to an array.

Comment: yep. `preg_match_all()` will return the matches in an array. Any doubts?

Comment: Yes, it counts as a match, but doesn't show the captured words. Checkout your example. It matches the words (blue), but doesn't capture them (green).

Comment: Yeah! Now it works perfectly, thanks for your patience. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are capturing folder

try

```
\/folder\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+
```

Comment: This will capture just the first word *one* for `/folder/one/two/three`. I've [changed your suggestion](http://regex101.com/r/nK9zO1/2) to `\/folder\/|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` and worked great for me. Thanks @ant!

Comment: Drux, your new suggestion doesn't seem to work for `/folder`. It still captures the word folder.

Comment: Yes, you're right @B. Dalton! And it captures a white space for `/folder/one/two/three`.

Comment: @drux did you want to capture one, two ,three in this `/folderone/two/three`

Comment: @drux this is incorret.it will not return `two` or `three`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:\/folder)?\/?|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/10

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @vks, this is what I'm talking about.  :)

Comment: it is capturing whitespaces! Could we eliminate them?

Comment: @drux it is not.see demo link . there are only 3 matches.

Comment: @drux whitespaces?? where?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, check vks's example. There are more matches than captured words.

Comment: @drux the matches are shown at the right side.There are only three?

Comment: so you don't want to match anything other than one,two,three.

Comment: Yes @vks. It shows just three words: *one*, *two* and *three*. But checkout the match count on the top. It shows more matches than words. In my PHP code, it populates an array with blank values and captured values.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I want just the *one*, *two* and *three* params to populate an array.

Comment: @drux try `\/folder?\/?|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+`

Comment: @drux check out my answer.. Vks , he don't want to match anything other than one, two,three

Comment: @vks, I'm not sure if we can handle match and find separately. Your example returns no captured word for `/folder`, but shows **1 match** on top. In this case, PHP `preg_match_all()` will return TRUE and set an empty value as found.